# writing a deepcopy without using deepcopy

Tags: python, loops, nested-lists

So I need to make a deepcopy of a nested list but without using the import copy. I have a sepereate function that outputs Board
`Board = [['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], ['B', 'B', '', 'W', 'W'], ['W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W'], ['W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W'], 0]`

So I thought of doing this to make a deepcopy using for loop:

```
def copy(b: Board) -> Board:
    if isinstance(b, list):
        return [copy(item) for item in b]
    else:
        return b
```

But when doing this I think I just returns b without making a deepcopy, since the 0 at the end is an integer?
Am I also correct in thinking that to test if I made a correct deepcopy I can do the following to confirm:

```
copy == Board 
True 
copy is Board
False
```

when returning copy i get the following:
`[['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], ['B', 'B', '', 'W', 'W'], ['W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W'], ['W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W'], 0]`
but when trying to test with "==" and "is" I get:

```
copy == make_Board
False
copy is make_Board
False
```

Comment: `copy` is a function. You can't expect comparing a function to a list to _ever_ be true; they're different kinds of things, so comparing them (without overrides to force it to be otherwise) is unconditionally false. If you want to compare _the result of calling_ the function to something, you need to actually do the call.

Comment: Add your own answer using "Add an Answer", not by editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

To make a copy of the Board you can use next example:

```py
Board = [
    ["B", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    ["B", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    ["B", "B", "", "W", "W"],
    ["W", "W", "W", "W", "W"],
    ["W", "W", "W", "W", "W"],
    0,
]


def copy_board(b):
    return [item[:] if isinstance(item, list) else item for item in b]


new_Board = copy_board(Board)
new_Board[0][0] = "XXX"

print(Board)
print(new_Board)
```

Prints:

```
[
    ["B", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    ["B", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    ["B", "B", "", "W", "W"],
    ["W", "W", "W", "W", "W"],
    ["W", "W", "W", "W", "W"],
    0,
]

[
    ["XXX", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    ["B", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    ["B", "B", "", "W", "W"],
    ["W", "W", "W", "W", "W"],
    ["W", "W", "W", "W", "W"],
    0,
]
```

Comment: Question was caused by a syntax misunderstanding (that someone else reimplementing `deepcopy` is unlikely to share) and thus eligible for close-as-typo, is it not?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I read the title `writing a deepcopy without using deepcopy` but after the edit and clarification, you're right - OP should add his answer here and not to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the question about whether "==" and "is" confirms a deepcopy, I wrote it wrong. Should be written as:

```
copy(Board) is Board 
False
Copy(Board) == Board
False
```

But only "is" is needed since it checks the objects id's. "is" should print out False for it to be correct.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).